# addEventListener works twice instead of one

Tags: javascript, carousel, addeventlistener

Im doing carousel and suddenly addEventListener('animationend', function(){}) running twice. I placed console.log to view "currentItem", and at the third time it running twice. Where is my mistake?
https://codepen.io/sundozer/pen/VwxENKw

```
squares[currentItem].addEventListener('animationend', function(){
        console.log(currentItem)
        squares[currentItem].classList.remove('toLeft')
        squares[((currentItem+1)+squares.length) % squares.length].classList.remove('fromRight')
        squares[currentItem].classList.add('hide')
        changeCurrentItem(currentItem+1)
```

Comment: It runs once in the codepen you provided.

Comment: I've never used animation events, but it looks like after the first cycle, you might be doubling up on events? can you not attach them outside the button click event?

Comment: @NickSlash he cannot add them outside of the click event because then all 3 circles will be listening at the same time and firing whenever they animate - which in this case two circles stop and start at the same time which breaks his desired functionality.

Comment: If you wanted to add the event listener once, you can. I was curious so I had a go https://codepen.io/nickslash/pen/xxjyoOp

Comment: Yeah I didn't doubt you can add them initially, but in his code the functionality broke. You managed to make it work while two events fire at the same time 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, whenever you click the button you are running a function which adds new event listeners. If you do not remove the event listeners then they will begin to stack. You can deal with this by saving a reference to the function you add and removing them after. I have fixed your codepen with the following code:

```js
const butR = document.querySelector('.butR')
const squareRed = document.querySelector('.squareRed')
const squarePink = document.querySelector('.squarePink')
const squareBlue = document.querySelector('.squareBlue')
const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.squares')
const container = document.querySelectorAll('.container')
let currentItem = 1;
let enable = 1;

const changeCurrentItem = (number) => {
    currentItem = number % squares.length;
}

butR.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (enable === 1) {
        squares[currentItem].classList.add('toLeft');
        squares[((currentItem+1)+squares.length) % squares.length].classList.add('fromRight');
        squares[((currentItem+1)+squares.length) % squares.length].classList.remove('hide');

        const animStart = function() {
            enable = 0;
        }

        const animEnd = function() {
            enable = 1;
            console.log(currentItem);
            squares[currentItem].classList.remove('toLeft');
            squares[((currentItem+1)+squares.length) % squares.length].classList.remove('fromRight');
            squares[currentItem].classList.add('hide');
            squares[currentItem].removeEventListener('animationstart', animStart);
            squares[currentItem].removeEventListener('animationend', animEnd);
            changeCurrentItem(currentItem+1);
        }

        squares[currentItem].addEventListener('animationstart', animStart);
        squares[currentItem].addEventListener('animationend', animEnd);
    }
})
```